# How do you create cookies and hide div?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm having an issue where cookies are not being set and popup message doesn't seem to hide itself I would admit I'm an amateur with javascript and this is my first time dealing with cookies. I had it working at one point but I can't seem to recreate what made it work

```
#consent-popup {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     padding: .5rem;
     background-color: #717171;
     color: white;
     opacity: 1;
     transition: opacity .8s ease;

     &.hidden {
     opacity: 0;
           }
}
```

```
<div id="consent-popup" class="hidden">
    <p>short View our <a href="terms-of-service.html">Terms and conditions</a> and <a href="privacy-policy.html">Privacy policy</a>. I <a id="accept" href="#">ACCEPT</a></p>
</div>
```

```
const cookieStorage = {
    getItem: (key) => {
        const cookies = document.cookie
            .split(';')
            .map(cookie => cookie.split('='))
            .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, [key.trim()]: value}), {});
        return cookies[key];
    },
    setItem(key, value) {
        document.cookie = `${key}=${value}`;
    },
};

const storageType = cookieStorage;
const consentPropertyName = 'rnc_cookies';

const shouldShowPopup = () => !storageType.getItem(consentPropertyName);
const saveToStorage = () => storageType.setItem(consentPropertyName, true);

window.onload = () => {
    const consentPopup = document.getElementById('consent-popup');
    const acceptBtn = document.getElementById('accept');

    const acceptFn = event => {
        saveToStorage(storageType)
        consentPopup.classList.add('hidden');
    };

    acceptBtn.addEventListener('click', acceptFn);

    if (shouldShowPopup(storageType)) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            consentPopup.classList.remove('hidden');
        }, 2000);
    }
};
```

Comment: I have bad news for you if you think you've been working with Java: your code is actually in Javascript. Java and Javascript are not the same thing at all. Please edit your question and set the tags properly or you're a lot less likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: @MarsAtomic lol you are right, sorry it's been a long day